# Image swaping with click on <tr>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've edited this piece of code from the Data Tables Plugin witch makes a tr click able and pops open another tr with details from the clicked tr. This piece of code is the event listener for opening and closing. When "details" are open the img should be images/details_close.png and they are closed the img should be images/details_open.png and have a swap occurring when it opens and closes when clicked. What is happening is there is no swap going on when its open or closed I still only get the "details_open.png". I don't knoe if I'm just not selecting the img tag properly or whats going on.

Link to project:
http://www2.kent.k12.wa.us/ksd/it/www/mobile/elementary.html

```
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'td', function (e) {
        var myImage = $(this).find("img");
        var nTr = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
        if ( oTable.fnIsOpen(nTr) )
        {
        /* This row is already open - close it */
        myImage.src = "images/details_open.png";
        oTable.fnClose( nTr );
        }
        else
        {
        /* Open this row */
        myImage.src = "images/details_close.png";
        oTable.fnOpen( nTr, fnFormatDetails(oTable, nTr), 'details' );
        }
    } );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is what I ended up with joining answers from you guys and doing some editing this is what solved the problem.

```
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
        var myImage = $(this).find("#more");
            var nTr = $(this).closest('tr')[0];
            if ( oTable.fnIsOpen(nTr) )
            {
            /* This row is already open - close it */
            myImage.attr("src","images/details_open.png");
            oTable.fnClose( nTr );
            }
            else
            {
            /* Open this row */
            myImage.attr("src","images/details_close.png");
            oTable.fnOpen( nTr, fnFormatDetails(oTable, nTr), 'details' );
            }
        } );
```

Comment: glad you came up with a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Two parts:

First, modify your image selector because you are within the TD, not the TR

```
var myImage = $(this).parent().find("img");
```

Second, use the attr() method to change the value of the src attribute instead of acting on src directly

```
myImage.attr("src","images/details_open.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var myImage = $(this).parent().find("img");
```

From your description, you are trying to swap an image somewhere in a TR, but your click handler is on all the TDs. In order to search for images in the TR, you would need to do a find() within the parent of the TD.

Comment: You can check out the project at the link I updated. That didn't work btw.